# Контейнер временных данных php

Tags: php, кэширование, mysql

Всем привет. Появилась трудность при реализации.
Ситуация такая: Выводятся комментарии в цикле, у каждого комментария есть автор, но чаще всего (80%-90%) необходимо отображать одного и того же человека.

Если задать так: Если юзер совпадает с ид юзера, то это основной автор и сохранить данные для дальнейшего использования, иначе делать запрос к базе и вытаскивать данные.

Первое, что пришло в логову, кеширование, но в моем случае, я не могу его использовать. Придется использовать альтернативу. Подумал на счет cookie, но они так же могут подвести, мне кажется. Что можно использовать в данном случае. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял Ваша задача такая: есть комментарии от пользователей (в порядке поступления): 
Вася, Петя, Петя, Вася, Вася, Оля, Петя, Вася
Можно первым запросом получить все комментарии для данной темы, из этого запроса выделить уникальные имена, и вторым запросом запросить у БД

```
SELECT id, аватарка, подпись, статус, постов FROM users WHERE nick=вася OR nick=Петя OR  nick=Оля
```

Далее остается только создавать красивое оформление комментариев не заботясь о излишних запросах к БД.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу смысла в промежуточном хранении такой информации. MySQL кэширует запросы, поэтому намного быстрей будет доставать информацию о пользователе из базы чем кэшировать и постоянно заботится о состоянии кэша где либо еще. А глобальные переменные вещь коварная, к тому же избыток глобальных переменных внесет дополнительную путаницу в код.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте функцию и глобальную переменную в которой храните массивы, ключи которых равны `userID`.

Функция:

> Если юзер совпадает с ид юзера, то это основной автор и сохранить данные для дальнейшего использования, иначе делать запрос к базе и вытаскивать данные.

Comment: Не плохо. Сейчас попробую на практике. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не занимаетесь ли вы оптимизацией на спичках?
Перефразирую, является ли данная проблема, "бутылочным горлышком" приложения?

Юзеринфо вытаскивается из базы, повторный запрос к тому же id mysql скорее всего вытащит из кеша.

Comment: Жаль, что трачу на вас время. Мой вопрос конкретизирован, поэтому и ответа жду ясного. Дополнение вновь родившимся: оптимизация - не есть только кеш. Данные, которые нужны временно, не важные. Поместить в кеш не имею возможности. Вариант с печеньем в пролете. Глобальные переменные сделают свою функцию.